# Provisioning Microsoft Teams from azure function via pnp powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, pnp-powershell, microsoft-graph, microsoft-teams

I am provisioning Teams via PnP powershell and it requires -Scopes. The only way to get -Scope is through interactive log in. This further means (which i am thinking) is that you can not use "Apply-PnPTenantTemplate" for provisioning Teams from e.g Azure functions or other background task without interactive log in.

Is it possible to provision Teams via "Apply-PnPTenantTemplate" from e.g Azure functions or other background tasks without interactive log in?

Comment: Have you check this out? - https://bob1german.com/2019/03/12/provisioning-teams-with-azure-functions-and-microsoft-flow-part-1-solution-overview/

Comment: Yes, i checked this article. I was trying to figure out how to do it through PnP powershell though.